# IPA for the pronunciation of つづく

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce "つづく"?

[tsɯ̥dzɯkɯ] or [tsɯdzɯkɯ] or [tsɯzɯkɯ]

Any comment are welcomed, as long as you know how to use IPA to transcribe human speech.

---3/23 night---

Wiktionary: [t͡sɨᵝzɨᵝkɯ̟ᵝ]　I personally believe this one is possible since the pronunciation of t͡s and z is more front while k is back. The vowels are affected as a result.

ja.forvo.com/word/続く/#ja: all examples in this site gives pronunciation that omit none of the three "u" in "tsuduku".

[tsɯ̥dzɯkɯ̥] or [tsdzɯk]: This one is interesting. I also agree that pronunciative change may happen in a fast and continuous speech.

アクセント核がない、無声子音に挟まれている、という場合の /i/ /u/ が弱化・無声化する、というのは基本的な規則です。(Can I interpret it as the rule of dictionary pronunciation? I mean, when the speaker pronounce つづく isolatedly or no in a fast speecha, and hence the standard pronunciation.)

Answer (score 1):

"How do I pronounce X" is almost always a very difficult question to ask, because pronunciation is often dependent on the context of the word and (more importantly) the dialect used. You're looking for the dictionary form which is referenced [here](https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8F/#ja), so I'll assume that the correct pronunciation is the correct IPA for what these speakers are saying.

Pitch accent: つづく{LHH}
Speakers 1, 3, & 4: t͡sɯzɯkɯ
Speaker 2: t͡sɯᵝzɯᵝkɯᵝ

I know IPA isn't an exact science, but the second speaker definitely used a more rounded close back vowel, but never went fully into the "u" sound.

Based on this set at least, I'd put the correct pronunciation as "t͡sɯzɯkɯ" for the dictionary form. A waveform analysis of the files might find evidence for a "d͡z" sound somewhere in there, but I can't personally hear any of them using that.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktionary's entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8F#Japanese) has [[t͡sɨᵝzɨᵝkɯ̟ᵝ]], but that seems to show devoicing on the final vowel, which is incorrect.  I'm also not sure I totally agree with the use of [[ɨᵝ]] as the first two vowels.

Comment: I don't think I make labiality on /u/ that follows /s/ or /ts/ either...

Comment: This answers how it's *not* pronounced, but it doesn't really address how it *is* pronounced.  An answer should address the question directly.

Comment: @snailplane Though, you could also interpret this as a partial answer which specifies the IPA for most of the word and just leaves two parts ambiguous, so it is still valuable in that respect IMO. (While full answers are ofc better than partial answers, they aren’t required, right?)

Comment: @snailplane -- At the time I answered, the poster seemed to be asking purely for IPA.  This was the entirety of the question post (newlines rendered as **\n** since they're stripped from comments):  _"IPA for the pronunciation of つづく
How do you pronounce "つづく"? **\n**
**\n**
[tsɯ̥dzɯkɯ] or [tsɯdzɯkɯ] or [tsɯzɯkɯ]"_

Answer (score -1):

> How do you pronounce "つづく"?

つ
**ts** not "tsu つ" in うつす（写す/移す）

づ
**dzu** neither "dz" in roads nor "zu ず" in すずり（硯） or すずむし（鈴虫）

く
**k** not "ku く" in くにする（苦にする）

So, I pronounce it as "**tsdzuk**".

Comment: IPAは素人なので回答できないんですけど、少なくとも2音目の「づ」で[舌と歯茎をくっつける](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/有声歯茎破擦音)発音をする人、ほぼいないと思うんですが…発音しにくくないですか？

Comment: `I pronounce it as "tsdzuk"` <-- でも、ここ → https://ja.forvo.com/word/続く/#ja を聞きますと、4人とも「つ」「づ」「く」を3つとも有声音で発音してますけど…。最初の「つ」の母音の /u/ って、無声子音に挟まれていない（後に有声子音の /dz/ が続いてますし）から、無声化（母音弱化）しませんよね。。。

Comment: ^ naruto 現代の日本語話者で 「ず」「づ」や「じ」「ぢ」を区別して発音してる人なんていない…と言われてますよね…

Comment: @naruto: roads のdsでなく、鈴虫のずと違うと言いたいのですが、良い方法は無いですかね。明らかにちがいます。いまも「つづく」と発音していますが、「ず」と違って舌先がどこかにちょこっと触れています。roadsの位置とは違うでしょうが。

Comment: 九州あたりで[まだ区別が残ってる](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D#%E5%85%B1%E9%80%9A%E8%AA%9E)地域があるっぽいですね。標準語では、ごく自然に発音した場合、基本的には「すずむし」の「ず」と同じで良いんだと思います（ゆっくり発音するとか、意識してしまうと破裂音に近くなるかも）

Comment: @Chocolate: 最初のコメントに対して、つ・づ・くと発音してくださいというと全て母音が付きます。普通の会話のなかで、つ、くに母音を付けると疲れませんか。つづくは、流れの中で発音すると、３音節ではなく、「づ」に強制が入った一音節のようになります。一音節名に強制を入れて都筑（つづき）という人名や地名を発音するとあきらかにtsuとなります。

Comment: 「停電が続いています」とか言ったら最後の「す」が母音弱化・無声化しますが、「つ」は無声化しないですね。そもそも無声子音に挟まれていませんので。（アクセント核がない、無声子音に挟まれている、という場合の /i/ /u/ が弱化・無声化する、という基本的な規則のはご存知ですよね？）アクセント核がないので「づ」より弱くはなりますけど、母音弱化・無声化とは違うものですよ。「都築」の「つ」はアクセント核があるし、無声子音に挟まれてもいないので無声化しません。

Comment: @Chocolate: 意識して区別して発音するするではなく、発音された音を観察するとどうなのかです。他人の同意は不要です。「づ」は基本的に「つ」に続いたときの表記です。私は「つづく」の「つ」はtsでuを発音していません。従ってtsの舌の位置、すなわち舌の先がどこかに少し触っている状態のまま「づ」に移ります。「す」すなわち、suのuを発音したどこににも舌の先が触れていないまま「ず」に移行したときの明らかに舌の位置が違います。音に違いがあるかどうかは分かりませんが、舌の先がどこかに触れているかどうかの違いはあります。これは意識しての動きではありません。

Comment: `他人の同意は不要です。` -- wwww ほな最初からあなたには何を言っても無駄！音声学の話しても聞く耳なし！ってことですね笑笑笑

Comment: @Chocolate: 質問者は音声学ではなく、Chocolateさんはどう発音しますかと尋ねているように思います。

Comment: [dz] や [ts] は「舌を離す時にできる破擦音」という定義ですけど、mackygooさんはそれを舌を離さずに連続して発音できるんですか？　「づ」の時点で一旦離れた舌がもう一度歯茎に触れるというなら、「まあ珍しいけどそういう人もいるのかー」程度には思えますが、舌が一度も離れないのは物理的に不可能な気がします。

Comment: @naruto:おっしゃるとおり確かに離れます。私の間違いです。次に「つづく」「すずく」の「づ」と「ず」が違うかどうか試してみました。「つ」の時の口の形や舌の位置と、「す」の後半の「u」の時の口の形あるいは舌の位置さらには唇の緊張度合いが違うので、上記の「づ」と「ず」とでは直前の口の違いに引っ張られて少し音は違いますが、dzuとzuの違いではなく、zuの中での違いなのかとも思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Chocolate 無声子音に挟まれている、アクセント核がある、という場合の母音が無声化しない例をあげてくれませんか。I am curious.

Comment: @chika 「[きし]{HL}(騎士)」の「き」 k**i**shi（cf. [きし]{LH}(岸)）、「[おすし]{LHL}(お寿司)」の「す」 os**u**shi、「[ふくしま]{LHLL}(福島)」の「く」 ~k**u**shi~ とか。無声子音(s, k, など)に挟まれてますが、アクセント核があって、無声化しません。